# Convert a RenderTargetBitmap to a byte[] to be displayed on a embedded screen?

Tags: c#, arrays, bitmap, windowsiot

I'm trying to convert a RenderTargetBitmap to a byte array that will then get sent off to an external monochrome OLED screen. I know that for the bitmap to display correctly the bit/byte alignment should be LSB to MSB & Top to Bottom:

[image]

But I can't figure out how to get the RenderTargetBitmap's pixeldata in that format.

For the moment I've got:

```
        RenderTargetBitmap renderTargetBitmap; //This is already set higher up
        DataReader reader = DataReader.FromBuffer(await renderTargetBitmap.GetPixelsAsync());

        // Placeholder for reading pixels
        byte[] pixel = new byte[4]; // RGBA8

        // Write out pixels
        int index = 0;
        byte[] array = new byte[renderTargetBitmap.PixelWidth*renderTargetBitmap.PixelHeight];
        using (reader)
        {
            //THIS IS WHERE I THINK I'M SCREWING UP
            for (int x = 0; x < rHeight; x++)
            {
                for (int y = 0; x < rWidth; y++)
                {
                    reader.ReadBytes(pixel);
                    if (pixel[2] == 255)
                        array[index] = 0xff;
                    else
                        array[index] = 0x00;
                    index++;
                }
            }
        }
        sh1106.ShowBitmap(buffer); //Send off the byte array
```

Comment: Seems you don't use your x and y loop variables at all, and "index" variable is not updated anywhere and is always 0.

Comment: I just removed the `index++` by mistake when copying it to stack overflow. I've fixed it. And about the x and y loops, that's where I'm blocked. That entire part needs to be rewritten, but I can't figure out how.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue, this is what I did to get it working (It will convert the BGRA8 output to a 1BPP output that can then be used on a monochrome display, SSD1306 in my case)

At 1BPP output means that 8 pixels are stored in 1 byte.  So you need to convert every 4 bytes into 1 bit.

```
  public async Task Draw()
  {
     ActiveCanvas.UpdateLayout();
     ActiveCanvas.Measure(ActiveCanvas.DesiredSize);
     ActiveCanvas.Arrange(new Rect(new Point(0, 0), ActiveCanvas.DesiredSize));

     // Create a render bitmap and push the surface to it
     RenderTargetBitmap renderBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap();
     await renderBitmap.RenderAsync(ActiveCanvas, (int)ActiveCanvas.DesiredSize.Width, (int)ActiveCanvas.DesiredSize.Height);

     DataReader bitmapStream = DataReader.FromBuffer(await renderBitmap.GetPixelsAsync());

     if (_device != null)
     {
        byte[] pixelBuffer_1BPP = new byte[(int)(renderBitmap.PixelWidth * renderBitmap.PixelHeight) / 32];

        pixelBuffer_1BPP.Initialize();

        using (bitmapStream)
        {
           while (bitmapStream.UnconsumedBufferLength > 0)
           {
              uint index = (uint)(renderBitmap.PixelWidth * renderBitmap.PixelHeight * 4) - bitmapStream.UnconsumedBufferLength;

              for (int bit = 0; bit < 8; bit++)
              {
                 bitmapStream.ReadBytes(BGRA8);

                 byte value = (byte)(((BGRA8[0] & 0x80) | (BGRA8[1] & 0x80) | (BGRA8[2] & 0x80)) == 0x80 ? 1 : 0);

                 pixelBuffer_1BPP[index] |= (byte)(value << (7 - bit));
              }
           }

           _device.DrawBitmap(0, 0, pixelBuffer_1BPP, (short)renderBitmap.PixelWidth, (short)renderBitmap.PixelHeight, Colors.White);
        }
     }
  }
```